# Keycloak Instance not created using keycloak-js

Tags: javascript, keycloak

Keycloak (14.0) is configured for React+Typescript application and use of PKCE.
This set-up worked well when POC was carried out two months back.
But, now it's not working even with Keycloak 16.1.1 version.
'keycloak-js' version always kept in sync with server version.

```js
const keycloakConfig = {
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth',
    realm: 'my-realm',
    clientId: 'my-react-app'
}

const keycloak = Keycloak(keycloakConfig);
console.log('keycloak ==>' + JSON.stringify(keycloak));
```

Above code now logs output as:  `keycloak ==>{}`
Already spent a full day to solve the issue which might be small but unable to do so.
Any pointers to overcome the issue are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved in my project react-typescript with this

```
    import Keycloak, { KeycloakConfig } from "keycloak-js";

    const initOptions: KeycloakConfig = {
        url: "https://myurl/auth",
        realm: "myrealm",
        clientId: "myclient",
    };

    const keycloak = new Keycloak(initOptions);

    export default keycloak;
```

and later to wrap all in ReactKeycloakProvide

```
      <React.StrictMode>
            <ReactKeycloakProvider authClient={keycloak}>
                <App />
            </ReactKeycloakProvider>
        </React.StrictMode>
```